# Set a ContextMenu UserControl for a Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-contextmenu

I have created a custom context menu in a separate user Control Class CustomContextMenuUc.

The simple version of the code looks like this.

```
<ContextMenu x:Class="CustomContextMenu.CustomContextMenuUc"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description.Value}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.OverridesDefaultStyle>True</ContextMenu.OverridesDefaultStyle>
    <ContextMenu.Placement>Custom</ContextMenu.Placement>
</ContextMenu>
```

I want to use this `CustomContextMenuUc` in multiple Windows. I am able to assign this User control in C# code like

```
ContextMenuGrid.ContextMenu = new CustomContextMenuUc();
```

Where `ContextMenuGrid` is a grid.

I want to do this in XAML How should I do it?

```
<DataGrid ContextMenu="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to define the Resource in resources of your window like

```
<local:CustomContextMenuUc x:Key="MyContextMenu"/>
```

here `local` is the xmlns where your contextmenu is defined.

Then you can do

```
<DataGrid ContextMenu="{StaticResource MyContextMenu}">
```

Thanks